# Set Django session variables through channels (http_session)

Tags: python, django, session, channel, django-channels

According to the Django channel docs,

```
    You get access to a user’s normal Django session using the http_session 
    decorator - that gives you a message.http_session attribute that behaves 
    just like request.session. You can go one further and use 
    http_session_user which will provide a message.user attribute as well as 
    the session attribute.
```

Is there anyway I can set a session variable like so?
I did try it, and I get an error saying NoneType is not iterable.

```
if 'username' not in message.http_session:
    message.http_session['username'] = 'temp'
```

In other words, message.http_session returns a NoneType. I've tried using the decorators @http_session and @channel_session_user_from_http, but they didn't help either.

Comment: ... yes? Did you try?

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You just set the variable.

foo = 'bar'

And it persists throughout the session